# Remote Validation in jQuery not validating

Tags: ajax, json, validation, jquery-mobile

This form will INSERT both an email and password into my MYSQL db

First, I am trying to validate an email remotely to make sure it does not exists, and also that
the Pswd and Pswd2 are equal.

the script writes to the db, but the validation is not working. I am new to JQ and Ajax so any help would be apprecated.
Thanks.

FORM:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/additional-methods.min.js"></script>

   ... 
        <div data-role="content">
             <form  id="AddUser" class="ui-body ui-body-a ui-corner-all" data-ajax="true" >
                    <fieldset>
                        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                            <label for="Email">Email Address:</label>
                            <input id="Email" type="email" />
                        <label for="Pswd">Password:</label>
                            <input id="Pswd" type="password" /> 
                        <label for="Pswd2">Confirm Password:</label>
                            <input id="Pswd2" type="password" />    
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" id="submit" data-theme="b" name="submit" value="submit-value">Submit</button>
                    </fieldset>
        </form>     
        </div>

...
```

below is the js inside the document:

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function() { 

        var validator = 
        $('#AddUser').validate({ 
            rules: { 
                Pswd: { 
                    required: true, 
                }, 
                Pswd2: { 
                    required: true, 
                    equalTo: "#Pswd" 
                }, 
                Email: { 
                   required: true, 
                   email: true, 
                   remote: "process/ValidateEmail.php" 
                }
            }, 
            messages: { 
                Pswd: { 
                    required: "Provide a password", 
                }, 
                Pswd2: { 
                    required: "Repeat your password", 
                    equalTo: "Enter the same password as above" 
                }, 
                Email: { 
                    required: "Not A Valid Email Address", 
                    remote: "already in use"
                }
             }
        }); // end var validator

            if (validator)
            {
                $("#AddUser").submit(function(){        
                //make Variables
                var emailVar =$('input[id=Email]').val();
                var pswdVar = $('input[id=Pswd]').val();
                var pswdconfirm = $('input[id=Pswd2]').val();
                var querystring = "Email="+emailVar+"&Pswd="+pswdVar;

                $.post("process/AddUser.php",querystring);

            }); //end submit()
            }; // end if validator


    }); //end ready()

    </script>
```

the Validator file (ValidateEmail.php)

```
<?php 

    $UserEmail = $_POST["Email"];

    include "connection.php";

    $sqlEmail= mysql_query("Select EmailAddress from USERS where EmailAddress='$UserEmail'"); 
    $EmailCheck=mysql_fetch_array($sqlEmail);

    if (mysql_num_rows($EmailCheck) > 0) {
        echo json_encode(true);
    } else {
        echo json_encode(false);
    }

?>
```

Comment: SOLVED IT: I went back to formula and found some errors in the validation.php also the if(validation) is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

I went back to the code after some research and found it riddled with errors in both the js and the php validation:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
  {

    var validator = $("#AddUser").validate({
        rules: {
            Email: {
                required: true,
                email: true,
                remote: "process/ValidateEmail.php"
            },
            Pswd: {
                required: true,
            },
            Pswd2: {
                required: true,
                equalTo: "#Pswd"
            },
        },
        messages: {
            Pswd: {
                required: "Provide a password",
            },
            Pswd2: {
                required: "Repeat your password",
                equalTo: "Password Mismatch"
            },
            Email: {
                required: "Invalid Email",
                remote: jQuery.format("{0} is already used")
            }
        },
        // the errorPlacement has to take the table layout into account
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {

                error.appendTo(element.parent().next());
        },
        // specifying a submitHandler prevents the default submit, good for the demo
        submitHandler: function() {         

            //make Variables
            var emailVar =$('input[id=Email]').val();
            var pswdVar = $('input[id=Pswd]').val();
            var pswdconfirm = $('input[id=Pswd2]').val();
            var querystring = "Email="+emailVar+"&Pswd="+pswdVar;

            $.post("process/AddUser.php",querystring);

            $('#AddUser').clearForm();
        return false;

        },
        // set this class to error-labels to indicate valid fields
        success: 

            function(label) {
            label.html("&nbsp;").addClass("checked");

        }
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            email: { 
            required: true, 
            email: true, 
            remote: {
                url: "check-email.php",
                type: "post",
                data: {
                    email: function() {
                        return $("[name='email']").val();
                    }
                }
            }
          },
```

and the php must look like this:

```
$email= $_POST['email'];
include 'connect.php';
$email = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($email));
$query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users WHERE email = '$email'") or die(mysql_error());
echo (mysql_result($query, 0) == 1) ? 'false' : 'true';
```

be careful not to echo just false or true it must be echoed like this 'false' or true